# I can't find dynamically created textboxes on the page

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm trying to find my controls on the page with this click event.

EDIT to clarify: The user will enter in a loan number and press the btnLoanNumber_Click which will in tern call out to the database and populate the textboxes with information. The user will then update the textboxes by pressing btnEnter_1_Click.

EDIT Update: I added this line of code to see what would happen if I cleared the control before creating them and I get the following error:Multiple controls with the same ID

I don't understand. Does it matter that I'm using an UpdatePanel?

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
        CreateControls();
    }
```

This all seems so simple but I believe state is the cause and I'm not sure how to fix the problem.

```
    protected void btnLoanNumber_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Hydrate properties with Pricing class properties (Pricing DB column names)
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

        LoanNumber = tbxLoanNumber.Text;
        Session["LoanNumber"] = LoanNumber;
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfControls; i++)
        {
            if (properties[i].GetValue(PricingByLoanNumber, null) != null)
            {
                string id = "tbx" + properties[i].Name;

                var tbx = (TextBox)PlaceHolder1.FindControl(id);

                tbx.Text = properties[i].GetValue(PricingByLoanNumber).ToString();
            }
        }            
    }
```

The tbx is always null. What seems odd, is that if I try to create the controls in that event I get an error because more than one control with the same Id is found. What am I missing and how can I find my controls?

Here is the entire code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Servicing_Fix.Model;
using Servicing_Fix.DAL;
using System.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Servicing_Fix
{
public partial class Servicing_Fix : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string loanNumber = "";

    // Get Pricing Metadata
    Type type = typeof(Pricing);

    #region Properties

    protected Pricing PricingByLoanNumber
    {
        get { return GetPricingByLoanNumber(LoanNumber); }
    }

    protected string LoanNumber
    {
        get { return loanNumber.Replace(",", ""); }
        set { loanNumber = value.Replace(",", ""); }
    }

    protected int NumberOfControls
    {
        get { return type.GetProperties().Count(); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Page Events

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            CreateControls();
        }
        else
        {
            if (Session["LoanNumber"] != null)
            {
                LoanNumber = Session["LoanNumber"].ToString();
            }
        }


    }

    protected void btnLoanNumber_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Hydrate properties with Pricing class properties (Pricing DB column names)
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

        LoanNumber = tbxLoanNumber.Text;
        Session["LoanNumber"] = LoanNumber;
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfControls; i++)
        {
            if (properties[i].GetValue(PricingByLoanNumber, null) != null)
            {
                string id = "tbx" + properties[i].Name;

                var tbx = (TextBox)PlaceHolder1.FindControl(id);

                tbx.Text = properties[i].GetValue(PricingByLoanNumber).ToString();
            }
        }            
    }

    protected void btnEnter_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Hydrate properties with Pricing class properties (Pricing DB column names)
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfControls; i++)
        {
            var tbx = (TextBox)PlaceHolder1.FindControl("tbx" + properties[i].Name);

            if (tbx != null)
            {
                properties[i].SetValue(PricingByLoanNumber, tbx.Text);
            }                
        }

        UpdatePricingByLoanNumber(LoanNumber, PricingByLoanNumber);
        tbxLoanNumber.Text = "";
    }

    #endregion        

    #region Helpers

    private Pricing GetPricingByLoanNumber(string loanNumber)
    {
        var pricingDAL = new PricingDAL();

        return pricingDAL.GetPricingByLoanNumber(loanNumber);
    }

    private void UpdatePricingByLoanNumber(string loanNumber, Pricing pricing)
    {
        var pricingDAL = new PricingDAL();

        pricingDAL.UpdatePricingByLoanNumber(loanNumber, pricing);
    }

    private void CreateControls()
    {
        // Hydrate properties with Pricing class properties (Pricing DB column names)
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

        // Dynamically create labels and textbox controls
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfControls; i++)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            TextBox tbx = new TextBox();

            lbl.ID = "lbl" + properties[i].Name;
            tbx.ID = "tbx" + properties[i].Name;

            lbl.Text = properties[i].Name;               

            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lbl);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tbx);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
        }          
    }

    #endregion 
   }
}
```

Comment: you should create control on every time page load
call  CreateControls(); at every page load

Comment: I put CreateControls() in OnInit() and now I get the following error: Multiple controls with the same ID 'lblLOANNUMBER' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.

Comment: make sure after adding oninit() u are not calling again on page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [ASP.NET Modifying Control Tree Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779911/asp-net-modifying-control-tree-dynamically)

Try using viewstate to store your values.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to find them after creating them. You probably are calling the find event before the create event

Comment: But I need to get the values from the textboxes to persist them to the DB.

Comment: usually dynamically created fields are lost due to postback.. try using sessions to store values in your textboxes
check the following link: http://forums.asp.net/t/1261964.aspx/1
After storing them in sessions, the data in your textboxes will persist and they ll be inserted in the DB after your insert statements