# How to call javascript function after button click event ASP

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, events

I'm trying to make a button that deletes something from a database, but before that I want to run javascript that validates the request ("are you sure you want to delete?") and after the button click I want to remove the DIV that was deleted.
I'm having issues getting the latter one to work, cant seem to fix it.. I will provide some code samples:

**EDIT**

Retracted code. Concerns of wrongful plagiarism for my project.

The answers are still valid for people searching up the same question. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: Personally I would not be trying to do this via javascript. You've already posted back to the server. Why not just generate the list of comments after you've performed the delete server side? Taking a guess at your code only call `ShowMeeting` on page load if not a postback, then call it in your delete event handler *after* you've performed the delete.

Comment: If you insist on going down the javascript path add some debug code to your script. At the start of `deleteCommentDivdeleteCommentDiv` add `console.log("Deleting Comment")` to see if your method is being called and add `console.log(div)` after you've tried to find the div to check it has been found. Then after your page has refreshed after the delete you will have a better idea of what is happening. There is a good chance all this is happening before the DOM is fully loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call Javascript or jQuery from code behind I add an Ajax's `ScriptManager` control (from the Toolbar) on the ASPX below the `asp:Content` tag:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

And in the code behind:

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "myFunction", "alert('This is a test');", true);
```

And the button that causes the postback or "calls" the Javascript should be inside an `UpdatePanel`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnDelComment" runat="server" Text="Delete comment" />
</ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnDelComment" />            
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**UPDATE:**

Due that your controls are dynamically added, place the `MeetingContent` div inside the `<ContentTemplate>` tag and the `PostBackTrigger` must be removed because `btnDelComment` doesn't exists yet when the page is loaded:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="MeetingContent" runat="server">
        </div>
      </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I removed the `UpdateMode="Conditional"` as well.

Comment: I'm new so I just need to ask, does that mean I have to create the view in the aspx.cs file? I mean I have most my code for the dynamic view (including the buttons) in a seperate class now that just returns an HtmlGenericControl to the aspx.cs file. When I say "this" inside of the class where I generate the view, I'm just referring to the instance of the class and not the "Page" class

Comment: Your custom control's class is rendered inside the `<div id="MeetingContent"> ... </div>` right? If so, just place that div inside the UpdatePanel's `<ContentTemplate>` tag. The code I provided must be placed in the aspx file.

Comment: ^Oops Oops edit. Ive tried two solutions by inspired by you now. One where I dynamically create the updatepanel with the buttons (each with unique control id) and now I tried the solution with the updatepanel outside, but I think the problem I face is that I cant access the right  instance of the Page class in my ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), string, string, bool);

Comment: Did you try `System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), string, string, true);`? Just to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Place this code above `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` to see if it is actually reaching it: `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Here I am");` Take a look at your output console in VS.

Comment: I did not try that, but I tried it now and I get "System.ArgumentException: 'The control must be in the control tree of a page.'"

Comment: Yes I know the code runs, because the comments are deleted from the database

Comment: Ok, then this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779911/asp-net-modifying-control-tree-dynamically

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me, I see it might take me a little time to read up on this. I will update this later.

Answer (score 1):

You can in your button find the event OnClientClick and add the following:

`OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete');"`